# Bootstrap-sass > ie_hex_str not interpreted during assets precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, rails-3.1

I run into a quite strange issue :

I'm working with :

- Rails 3.1.1
- Bootstrap-sass 1.4.4 (didn't have time to upgrade to 2.0 yet)

An known issue in previous bootstrap-sass 1.4.0 was the one described [here](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/14) relating to IE gradients displays.
This was fixed in 1.4.3 by the introduction (from what I understood) of ie_hex_str function and specific filters for IE like :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{ie_hex_str($startColor)}', endColorstr='#{ie_hex_str($endColor)}', GradientType=0);
```

Some details are given [here](http://pinds.com/2011/11/30/fixing-ie-gradients-with-rails-3-1-and-scss/).

I still have the problem and my issue is that after the assets precompilation I get something like :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='ie_hex_str(#FFFFFE)', endColorstr='ie_hex_str(#E6E6E6)', GradientType=0);
```

That is the ie_hex_str was not interpreted when compiling the assets.
I didn't touch any of the bootstrap-sass code so I don't understand what's going on...

Any idea ?

**UPDATE :**

The "funny" thing is that I have 2 applications using the same versions of rails and bootstrap-sass and doing pretty much the same thing and they don't react the same way. For one  the ie_hex_str is correctly interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find out what was going on. It seems that the functions in the sass mixins of bootstrap-sass are not getting interpreted during assets precompilation.

As I couldn't figure out why, I used a workaround: I overrode the definitions I'm using such as btn :

```
.btn {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFFFFFE, endColorstr=#FFE6E6E6, GradientType=0);

  .primary {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FF049CDB, endColorstr=#FF0064CD, GradientType=0);
  }
}
```

Using the color I need.
At least it works well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be caused by the asset pipeline **initialize_on_precompile** setting in application.rb (Rails 3.1):

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

The "ie_hex_str" precompile issue appeared for us when including this line in application.rb. Removing/commenting resolved the issue.

- Rails 3.1.3
- bootstrap-sass 1.4.4